# Grunt Combine Media Queries - Cannot call method "join" of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, media-queries, gruntjs

I found the [Grunt Combine Media Queries](https://github.com/buildingblocks/grunt-combine-media-queries) plugin this morning and have been looking at getting it running on my build as we've got a stupid amount of media query declarations in our CSS (204 - We're using SASS) which I'd like to reduce.

```
cmq: {
    options: {
        log: true
    }
    , your_target: {
        files: {
         '<%= meta.cssPath %>temp': ['<%= meta.cssPath %>hayes.css']
        }
    }
}
```

cssPath  is just the dir the CSS is in.

When I run grunt cmq I get the following error:

```
Processed media queries:
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)
@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi)
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 768px)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
@media (min-width: 768px)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 767px)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 767px) and (max-width: 767px)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (min-width: 1200px)
@media (min-width: 979px)
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1200px)
@media (min-width: 1200px)
@media (max-width: 980px)
Warning: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Has anyone had anything similar or know what's causing this? I've got Grunt 0.4.1 running.

Comment: There are some very daft media queries in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a look and it appears this grunt task fails if there are comments within the media queries.

I've sent a pull request to fix this issue: https://github.com/buildingblocks/grunt-combine-media-queries/pull/5

If you are desperate, you are welcome to use my fork: https://github.com/badsyntax/grunt-combine-media-queries

Comment: Thanks. I've got around it by reworking on of the functions. I'll check your fork out in the morning. Ta.

Comment: The author of the grunt plugin has merged my fix. You can pull down the latest version via `npm install grunt-combine-media-queries@latest --save-dev` and it should work now. Mind to mark my answer as correct if this resolves your issue?